# ASP.Net MVC and jQuery DataTables plugin trouble

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to integrate the jQuery DataTables plugin into an ASP.Net MVC project. I am following the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part#BackgroundSSP). When I run just the sample code in a test project everything works. But when I try and debug it in my real application the `AjaxHandler`does not even get executed. Am I missing something?

Here is the calling jQuery Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/UX/AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [

                {
                    "sName": "ID",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {

                        return '<a href=\"Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                    }
                },
                { "sName": "NAME" },
                { "sName": "ADDRESS" },
                { "sName": "TOWN" },

            ]

        });
    });

</script>
```

Then my handler;

```
 public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = 97,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
            aaData = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {"1", "Microsoft", "Redmond", "USA"},
                new string[] {"2", "Google", "Mountain View", "USA"},
                new string[] {"3", "Gowi", "Pancevo", "Serbia"}
                }


        },
         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

Comment: I recall that its a little weird with the Ajax data, you may need to provide a first page of data when you first render the table.

Comment: Nothing showing in the network tab in developer tools on the browser?

Comment: Not in my main application. If I run the exact same code in a new project then I get the Json response in the network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the call to this view is being made from another controller other than ux:

```
"sAjaxSource": "ux/AjaxHandler",
```

If the call to this view is made from ux then you only need:

```
"sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
```

The extra slash you have in front of the ux is causing your grief

Also I as per our discussion your Id on your table was not the same as the ID your JS was referencing.

Comment: I tried that too, but didn't help. If I set a break point in the AjaxHandler during debugging it is not even getting hit. I think it may be something in the script but not sure.

Comment: ActionResult is a 'super-set' of JsonResult so that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: The AjaxHander is in the UX controller

Comment: Is this view populated from a different controller that ux?

Comment: No. It is all part of the UX controller

Comment: If they are all a part of the same controller drop the /ux/ and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: Tried that too. Really frustrating.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27790/discussion-between-robert-and-andy-j)